# Translate Salesforce default message when uploading files

Tags: translation

I'm working with an app in spanish to handle cases, I have the default component for uploading files, when a file is uploaded, the message "1 file was added to the Case" translated to spanish has an error, it has one space missing and shows like this "se ha agregado 1 archivo alCaso":
[image: Spanish error]

Where can I find this message so it can be translated correctly?

Comment: You should contact Support and log a bug. This is something that Salesforce needs to fix.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that, apparently that will be the only solution